# gradle: adding jar to web-inf

Tags: war, gradle

i have created a gradle build and added java, scala, war, jetty  code and its all working fine.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

List compileTime = [
                    "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.4@jar",
                    "org.scalatra:scalatra_2.8.0:2.0.0.M2@jar",
                    "org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.22@jar",
                    "com.mongodb.casbah:casbah_2.8.0:2.0.2@jar",
                    "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.8.1@jar"
            ]

List runTime = [
                    "org.scalatra:scalatra_2.8.0:2.0.0.M2@jar",
                    "com.mongodb.casbah:casbah_2.8.0:2.0.2@jar",
                    "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.8.1@jar"
            ]

//                  "org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211@jar",
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo urls: ["http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases","http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2","http://repo1.maven.org/maven2","https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots","https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"]
}

dependencies {
        scalaTools 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.8.1'
        scalaTools 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.8.1'
          compile compileTime
            runtime runTime
          testCompile "junit:junit:3.8.2"   
      } 

task myTask (type: War) {
  println configurations.runtime.collect
  println classpath()
 }

war {
   // from 'main/webapp' 
    webInf { from 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF' }
  //  classpath classpath() /
    classpath configurations.runtime

    webXml = file('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml') 
}
```

I like to 
1) Add only the necessary jars. in the war, in the above code i am getting Jetty and servlet jars in my war. !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For dependencies that should not go into the War, use the "providedCompile" or "providedRuntime" scope.

Some remarks on your build script:

1. You don't have to put dependencies on the "runtime" class path that are already on the "compile" class path. Gradle does this for you. Same for "providedCompile" and "providedRuntime".
2. Do you really have compile dependencies on servlet API and Jetty? (Could be true, just wondering.)
3. Your usage of "mavenRepo urls: ..." is wrong. You need to list the repos one by one. For more information, see [32.5.1 Maven repositories](http://gradle.org/latest/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:maven_repo) in the Gradle user guide.
4. Not sure why you use "@jar" everywhere. This effectively disables transitive dependency management. Maybe a result of 3. ?
5. Your "war { ... }" configuration is the default and can be omitted. See [23.6 War](http://gradle.org/latest/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#war_plugin) in the user guide.